# Civilization 4: time in own scenario runs up too quickly

Tags: modding

In Civilization 4 (Beyond the Sword) I started making a scenario that focuses on the colonization of North America. For added realism, I set the `StartYear=1780`.
Everytime I run the scenario, the time runs up far too quickly–probably because I set `Era=ERA_ANCIENT` and `GameTurn=0`–so that after just twenty turns the clock nears present day.

I'm not really sure how to go fix this, other than by playing an actual marathon game from the start up to the year 1780 and copy over the values.

Is there any way to calculate/know the right values for my scenario?

Answer (score 2):

You will want to open your worldbuilder save file, which by default is in

```
YourInstallDirectory\Sid Meiers Civilization IV\PublicMaps\
```

Open it with notepad or a similar program. You will probably want to set it to

```
Era=ERA_RENAISSANCE

For Calendar=: "The Calendar setting is used to determine the length in time of 
each turn in the scenario.  By default the calendar is set to default which 
means the scenario will use the same turn length time as the normal game. 
Valid options include CALENDAR_YEARS (each turn is one year), 
CALENDAR_SEASONS (each turn is one season: Winter, Spring, 
Summer, Autumn), CALENDAR_MONTHS (each turn is one month) 
and CALENDAR_WEEKS (each turn is one week, with four weeks to the 
month)."
```

[Read more about the world builder.](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=132800)

Comment: Setting `Era=ERA_RENAISSANCE` makes the game start on turn 555 and well past the year 7000. I'm pretty sure changing the calendar setting will make time pass in a linear fashion, resulting in strange science levels late game.